# Google Sheets script conditional formatting a cell based on value of that cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Google sheet where one column contains values.  It is column number 10 in the sheet and I need the cells of that column to change color if the cell contains the word 'Declined'. I am having issues.  Here is what I have tried

```
var statusColumn = sheet.getRange(10, sheet.getLastRow()-1);
var oValues = statusColumn.getValues();

  for (var i = 0; i < oValues.length; i++) {
    if (oValues[i] == 'Declined'){
      sheet.getRange().setBackGroundColor('yellow');
    }
  }
```

This does not work.  Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- From `It is column number 10 in the sheet`, you want to search the values of the column "J".
- You want to set the background color of cell, when the cell value is `Declined`.

If my understanding is correct, how about this modification?

#### Modification points:

- `var statusColumn = sheet.getRange(10, sheet.getLastRow()-1)` is one cell. In your situation, you can use [`getRange(row, column, numRows)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow-column-numrows).
- You can use `setBackground(color)` instead of `setBackGroundColor()`.

#### Modified script:

```
var statusColumn = sheet.getRange(1, 10, sheet.getLastRow(), 1); // For example, if you want to retrieve the values from row 2, please modify to sheet.getRange(2, 10, sheet.getLastRow(), 1);
var oValues = statusColumn.getValues();
for (var i = 0; i < oValues.length; i++) {
  if (oValues[i][0] == 'Declined'){
    sheet.getRange(i + 1, 10).setBackground('yellow');
  }
}
```

#### Note:

- In your question, the top row of cell you want to retrieve is not shown. So in this modified script, `1` was used.

#### References:

- [getRange(row, column)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getRange(Integer,Integer))
- [getRange(row, column, numRows)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow-column-numrows)
- [setBackground(color)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setbackgroundcolor)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the result you want, I apologize. At that time, can you provide a sample Spreadsheet including what you want? I would like to modify the script.